# do I have to register as a shopify partner?

Tags: shopify

(I am reposting this question here because I tried on the google news group and got no responses.)

I need to build a shop for my client, and the client already has a domain and a web site. I need to integrate e-commerce functionality in to the site. This is going to be done by sending AJAX requests to the API.

my question is whether I need to get a partner account for this? I am not yet going to write an app that people would install, I am just building a store for my client. how is it done?

Comment: why don't you just ask their support? I assume they can answer all account-related questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a Shopify Partner account for this. You can instead create a "Private application" within the normal shopify admin, which will give you the api credentials you need to make stuff happen.

This article on the shopify wiki gives a good overview of the process for getting started (the first sections are most relevant in your case):

http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_api_gem_with_the_credentials_of_a_private_app